# Apple Mail not to include attachments?

Tags: mail.app, email, attachments

When I send an email from gmail.com, the attachments I add aren't included in the (rich text/html) email. However, if I attach images to an email via Mail all the images (videos as well) are included in the message.

I would like to disable this behavior, how can I do that?

One is sent from gmail.com another is from Apple Mail (mail.app):
[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry, you do not make sense, try again, what do you want to disable ? what does the web version of gmail has to do with that? If you attach something to email in Mail app it should be send with it, if not then not.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I will try again: so when you attach a word doc of 3 thousand lines to gmail it won't append it to the end of the letter. If I attach multiple images, it won't do either. (just think of text emails for instance, it wasn't always rich text/html...)

However, if I attach a picture / video in Apple Mail to an email it appends it to the end of it... What I want is to have all the attachments listed when I get the same letter, without having them included into the message...
I hope I was clear now, please let me know if you didn't get it

Comment: It's still somewhat confusing. How does the result differ in Gmail and Mail? Does only one of them actually attach/send the attachment or are the attachments placed differently in the mail? Maybe adding (links to) screenshots will make it easier to understand as well

Comment: @patrix I added images. I think I figured it out. It's entirely the fault of apple mail: both of the above messages (which look different same at gmail.com) look quite the same. I'm afraid I cannot change that :(

Comment: @Buscar웃 Please see my above comment

Answer (score 1):

Both (gmail and apple) treat attachments differently. 
If you right click the PDF or Word document you should be able to choose from the menu, show as icon.

If you want to permanently show the attachments as icons in Apple Mail, close Apple Mail, open Terminal and issue the following command

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes
```

If you want to undo what you just did-
Close Apple Mail, open Terminal, copy and paste the following command

```
defaults delete com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing
```